# How to make F8 my run shortcut in OSX Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I went to preferences, general, keys, then down to run. I highlighted run and unbinded it then attempted to hit the F8 button on my MacBook but as soon as I did this my apple music started to open. When I type F8 in manually it just gives me a space between them, and thereafter doesn't work.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can treat your function keys as "standard function keys" by selecting the `Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys` option in the `Keyboard` section of `System Preferences.app`.

[System Preferences: Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Q9A.png)

Comment: Thanks!
Where exactly is that option located? I description:, binding:, and when:. Then beside that is a box that says conflicts.

Comment: It's in the Keyboard tab of the Keyboard section inside the **System Preferences** app (not Eclipse). It's a system-wide change, unfortunately.

Comment: Jeez Idk what I did but now Eclipse won't allow me to type the letter 'f' into projects. The 'f' works good everywhere else. Any ideas of what might have happened?

Comment: It's possible that you bound the `f` key to perform an action in the Eclipse preferences.

Comment: ok, the 'f' was fixed by restoring it to default settings. I can't believe there isn't another way to have a single keyboard key run run w/o having to switch to the use all f1,f2 setting....